# How to download all files from a GitHub repository but not zipped by GitHub?

Tags: download

I want to download all files from a GitHub repository but not zipped by GitHub (i.e. not inside one zip archive automatically created by GitHub's system), rather I just want to download all the files whatsoever from a repository to a local directory in my operating system.

- I don't use Git
- `wget -r --no-parent https://github.com/USER/REPOSITORY` doesn't do that; I get an endless loop of the following output:

> Connecting to github.com|140.82.121.4|:443... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response...

Comment: Is there any reason you can not `git clone` the repository?

Comment: Oh, I don't use Git, at all, I have updated the question to include that important detail.

Comment: Is there a reason you won't use Git, or is it just that you don't know Git?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax it's a side discussion that I prefer not to take part in here in this comment section.

Comment: The thing is you want us to give a solution without using the two tools that are designed for this: git and github's downloads. So you're basically asking us to jump through hoops that make no sense, this is why people are asking why you need this, so we can understand what limitations you face and find a solution and avoid an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). Otherwise, the answer is "just use git" or "just download the zip". The answer you have received is just downloading the zip (tgz, in this case).

Comment: @terdon I want to download files from a directory (some of these files may be directories by themselves), and I ask how to do that so perhaps I had a mistake designating the question to GitHub specifically? (I could have asked about any other code hosting website for that matter).

Comment: Ah, yes. The focus on git isn't helping since git provides the functionality already. On the other hand, the details will depend on how the remote server is set up and whether the files really are on a real directory hierarchy.

Comment: If you make the question more generic, the answer is going to be `wget -r -np` or one of its mirroring options, and you won’t be any closer to solving your actual problem. If you explain what you’re really trying to do, you’ll have a better chance of getting an answer that is actually useful to you.

Comment: @terdon I just tried git clone, it's easier to use than I thought, but, luckily I have Git in my shared server environment; I am not sure every shared server will have it, that's why I looked for a non Git Way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

```bsh
curl -L  "https://github.com/ORGANIZATION/REPO/archive/BRANCH_NAME.tar.gz" | tar -xzf -
```

You need to know the branch as well. Its name is `main` by default usually.
This can be simple in case of single repo: you do not need automate it.
If you want to download multiple repositories, you should consider that they can use multiple branches. For example one for releases, one for integration and so on.

---

###### UPDATE

Another option - if you do use `git`, you can do:

```bsh
git clone --depth 1 'https://github.com/ORG/REPO.git' && rm -rf REPO/.git
```

Comment: About the first command, in `archive` the main branch is kept, so that's why you also added "archive", right?

Comment: I added ```archive```, because that is how GitHub provided the download URL. I think this is an undocumented behaviour.

Comment: I found this in the documentation, but I do  not have shell access to test it right now: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#download-a-repository-archive-tar